# How to find a keyword in a decomposed string on swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, chatbot, keyword, swift5

While trying to make a Chatbot, I managed to decompose the sentence, but I don't know how to check if there is a keyword (in my arrays) 
my code:

```
var array1 = ["dog", "cat", "bird"]     //my arrays "key words"
var array2 = ["wolf", "sheep", "pig"]
var array3 = ["horse", "frog", "bear"]
var sentence = "" // This would be whatever we write in the text field

let random = Int.random(in: 0...2) 

if random == 0 {
    sentence = "I like my dog"
}
else if random == 1 {
    sentence = "I like my pig"
}
else if random == 2 {
    sentence = "I like my horse"
}

let result = sentence.split(separator: " ") //this make the decomposition of the sentence
print(result)
```

Then I tried to check if there was a keyword but it won't work, this is what I tried:

```
for counter in 0...array1.count-1 {   
    if result == array1[counter] {
        print("cool!")
    }
}
```

it gaves me: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '[String.SubSequence]' (aka 'Array') and 'String'

Comment: `for word in array1 {
    if result.contains(word[...]) {
        print("cool!")
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

`result` is an array and `array1[counter]` is a string; you cannot compare an array to a string, you can compare a string/substring to a string/substring or an array to an array. You can compare `result == array1` or `result[x] == array[y]`, with `x` and `y` being indices of the arrays. If you want to test if a string is within an array, then you can call `.contains(...)` on an array, see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945493-contains). Yet as your result array is an array of substrings, you need to make sure your test arrays are as well:

```
let array1 = ["dog", "cat", "bird"] as [Substring]
// ...
for word in array1 {
    if result.contains(word) { print("Cool") }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just convert every word from your sentence into a `String`.

```
let words = sentence.split(separator: " ").map { String($0) }
```

And used sets instead of arrays:

```
var keywords1: Set = ["dog", "cat", "bird"]     //my arrays "key words"
var keywords2: Set = ["wolf", "sheep", "pig"]
var keywords3: Set = ["horse", "frog", "bear"]

...

if !keywords1.isDisjoint(with: words) {
   print("Cool!")
}
```

Because with sets it's much easier to check for intersection.

Comment: Sets is of course a much more efficient solution here as it is O(1) vs O(n) for `contains`, yet converting an array of Substrings to an array of Strings at runtime and again for every new sentence is very inefficient. Declare the keyword Sets to be Sets of Substrings and you can skip the mapping step altogether and the compiler can perform this conversion at compile time (so there is no overhead whatsoever involved).